# Segmentation fault while running docker

Tags: docker

First I did
docker exec -it mysql bash
and then, tried to take a db backup using below command:
mysqldump -u [UserName] -p[Password] -R [DB_Name] > [DB_Name].sql

Being the sql is huge it terminated giving an error.
Now I am not being able to do any docker operation. Even docker ps is giving "Segmentation fault" error. I can understand it ran out of space due to the db backup file. But how to delete the sql file to free space.
I am using docker through terminal from windows 10 machine.

How to delete the database backup (sql) file to free space so that docker can run?
Please help.

Comment: Are you using WSL, WSL2, or Docker for Windows?

Comment: Docker for Windows.

Comment: The problem got resolved after system restart.